# How to achieve Column level Security in Powerbi?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

While working on Power BI, I have to show few columns from TABLE visual to specific set of users and hide for others.

So, till now I have created two ROLE in Power BI and added users but unfortunately, I am not able to hide and show TABLE Columns as per ROLE.

Answer (score 0):

At this point - Column Level Security and Hiding Columns is not something one can achieve with Power BI.

Kindly see [this Post](https://ideas.powerbi.com/forums/265200-power-bi-ideas/suggestions/15578172-column-level-security-for-reports) on Power BI Ideas.